# Local Schedule Notification react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I am new to React Native i'm trying to implement a functionality where the app sends to user everyday at a certain period of dates and times  a notifications  to remind users to take pills ( times and dates and data are stored in mongodb server so i'll be using axios to fetch them ) 
can notifications still works if app is closed or in the background ?
is it easy to make it work ?
Does anyone know of a way to achieve this , is it possible ?

thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to do something like this.

Comment: @RohitKashyap did you find a solution? Same requirements here

Answer (score 5):

Yes!!! This is possible. You have many options which includes:

1) Use a background-fetch for iOS and HeadlessTask in Android, here is a decent library 
 https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task

2) Push notifications from a server to ensure deterministically that the app wakes app (except it having been killed by the OS). In iOS, ensure that you call notification.finish() to avoid being discriminated by the task handler algorithm.

A Simple example for no 1 goes like this (NOT TESTED!!):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'
import { Notifications, Permissions, Constants } from 'expo';

BackgroundTask.define(async () => {

 // if time is 12pm, fire off a request with axios to fetch the pills info
  const response = await fetch('http://pills-server')


    const text = await response.text()

  // Data persisted to AsyncStorage can later be accessed by the foreground app
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MyApp:key', text)  

  // Notification configuration object
  const localNotification = {
        title: text,
        body: 'msg',
        data: data,
        ios: {
          sound: true
        }
      }

 // trigger notification, note that on ios if the app is open(in foreground) the notification will not show so you will need to find some ways to handling it which is discribed here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications

      Notifications
         .presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification)
         .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
         })


      BackgroundTask.finish()
})

class MyApp extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    // allows the app to recieve notifications (permission stuff)
    this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(() => {
      BackgroundTask.schedule()
    });

  }

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {

    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      return;
    }
    let deviceToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()

  }



  render() {
    return <Text>Hello world</Text>
  }
}
```

For the second one, the idea is somehow the server should have like a cron job that periodically, sends notification to all user devices based on their different timings/date and pills information stored in the database.

N.B for the server side implemention for expo u can use https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node for node.js projects, other sdks are listed here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Notifications, Permissions, Constants } from 'expo';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

class App extends React.Component {

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    // prevent device from registering more than once
    if (status !== 'granted') {
     return;
    }

    // get unique token of the device that the server can use to push notification to 
    the device
    let deviceToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();

    // call a method that sends the device token to the server, in which server stores somewhere and uses in the future
    this.props.registerToken({ deviceToken }).then(() => {

     // the listener here, is called whenever a push notification comes from the server or when the user clicks on the notification at the device tray
      this.notificationSubscription = 
         Notifications.addListener(this.handleNotification);
    })
  }

  handleNotification = (notification) => {

    if (notification.origin === 'selected') {
      // The notification was clicked from the tray by the user i.e selected
      // do stuff to handle selection
    } else {
     // The notification originated from the server
      const localNotification = {
        title: notification.title,
        body: notification.message,
        data: data,
        ios: {
          sound: true
        }
      }
      Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }

  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(() => {
    });

  }


  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <Text>Helllo world</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please Note that these solutions have not been tested and may contain some bugs, but the general idea remains the same and can be tweaked :).

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm using mongoose as a server can this works only by using the first method like getting the date and time from the server and generate local notification or the server side step (adding a cron job ) is necessary ?

Comment: Adding a cron job is for the second approach, u can use only the first one

Comment: will i get notifications if the app is closed ? or all the notifications will fire as soon as i open the app and i was trying to implement the first method but i got this erreur  (Couldn’t get GCM token for device
) ?

Comment: You should get the notifications when the app is closed with the help of the ‘background’ library. At what point are you getting the error? Also not that u may get errors if you are not running the app with ‘expo start’

Comment: i'm using react native expo so i'm always running the project with expo start

Comment: @Mazino Re. first approach: "// if time is 12pm, fire off a request with axios to fetch the pills info." What if at the specified time user is not connected to the internet or the fetch API throws error. What should be the strategy to re-fetch